# Problem to build an app - Heroku / Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, build

I dont know what is the problem and I already search I lot but I dont find a solution /
ps: Its working locally

Log:

```html
2021-04-27T17:19:31.439308+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2021-04-27T17:19:31.439845+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 start script.
2021-04-27T17:19:31.440436+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-04-27T17:19:31.484421+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-27T17:19:31.486598+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-04-27T17:19:31.486969+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-04-27T17_19_31_448Z-debug.log
2021-04-27T17:19:31.571932+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-04-27T17:19:31.655370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-04-27T17:19:33.743010+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=strateegia-trello-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=9329fa95-97d4-425b-879d-17378a687872 fwd="45.187.85.169" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-27T17:19:34.055438+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=strateegia-trello-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=8c16c47c-645e-4db8-8b90-53f221d79d14 fwd="45.187.85.169" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Package.json:

```html
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.16.1"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon src/server.json"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.3",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Procfile:

```html
web: npm start
```

In the end of the server.js, I have:

```html
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3333);
```

The structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UDyB.png)

Comment: "start": "nodemon src/server.json"  I think it  needs to be server.js not server.json

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that could work. Please let me know if it does.
You seem to have a node application, yet in the Procfile you don't usually give the command npm start. You give the starting javascript file.

Try something like:

```
Procfile: web app.js 
// Whatever is the name of your main javascript file name.
```